# Silence sysstat-collect.service?

Tags: linux, centos, systemd, centos5

The sar tool collects load values every 10 minutes on my CentOS Linux release 8.5.2111
via the service sysstat-collect.service. It fills /var/log/messages with:

```
Dec 26 12:50:04 node systemd[1]: Starting system activity accounting tool...
Dec 26 12:50:04 node systemd[1]: sysstat-collect.service: Succeeded.
Dec 26 12:50:04 node systemd[1]: Started system activity accounting tool
```

Every 10 minutes. That's annoying, I want to silence it. Is it possible??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `logrotate` to select what logs you want to keep or delete

Comment: but the problem appears on /var/log/messages not with logrotate.

Comment: you can use logrotate to rotate any kind of file you want, for example here https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s2-log_rotation they used it for var log messages

Comment: I don't want to rotate. I wan't to silence